# Structuring Pong

Tags: c++, opengl, structure, glut, pong

I am making Pong using C++ and OpenGL using Visual Express 2010. It is one of the first games I have made, and I am wondering how to best structure it. The main part that is stumping me is the game menu. Should I put the different game modes in different functions, and have a switch in my main function? For example, in Main.cpp, I would include the line

```
glutDisplayFunction(maincode)
```

In another file, I would define maincode as something like such (again, psuedocode):

```
maincode():
    switch m:
       case 1:
           singleplayer = true
           multiplayer = false
           menu = false
       case 2:
           singleplayer = false
           multiplayer = true
           menu = false
       case 3:
           singleplayer = false
           multiplayer = false
           menu = true
```

I would then, in each file, check to see the values of singleplayer, multiplayer, and menu to determine which mode I am in, then display code accordingly.

However, I get the feeling that this method would get much more complicated as the game gets more complicated, so I don't think this is the proper way to do it.

How should I structure the game and menu?

P.S. I am a C++ programmer for a living, but I just don't have experience programming games.

Comment: The scope of this question is vast. I suggest reading a book on game programming.

Comment: one cannot have both single player and multiplayer true, so they are mutually exclusive. keep one single `multiplayer` and if it is `true` the game mode multiplater, if it is `false` it is singleplayer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just unnecessary complexity to have 3 distinct `bool`s (totaling to 8 different states, 3 of which would be valid) when the only information you need is which mode you are currently in.

Better use an enumeration, i.e.

```
enum GameMode {

  GM_SinglePlayer, GM_Multiplayer, GM_Menu

};
```

and a single variable of type `GameMode`:

```
GameMode mode;
mode = GM_Menu;
```

Having different, *mutually exclusive* (that's the point that you missed here!) states to switch in between is an important concept in programming, so you are definitely on the right track. Keep working.

Comment: I understand what you are saying (enum is a much better method of doing it, I can't believe I had never thought of that!), but I am wondering if this sort of method is sound in the first place.

Comment: It's common practice (especially for small games such as Pong) to have your game states structured like this. Usually there's a main loop that dispatches the work to the menu or the game logic depending on the current state. So you're doing well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to organize a GUI application is using the [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Either that, or it's small modification [presenter first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presenter_First).

Knowing that, answers to such questions as your are simple to answer (Alexander Gessler's answer is quite ok)

Answer (score 0):

`glutDisplayFunc()` is a quick way to display stuff but it quickly becomes more trouble than it's worth when writing simple projects.

Unless you're multithreading and keeping a constant copy of your game-state for glutDisplayFunc() to read, I'd say avoid using it - and even then, probably, too.

For game loops, I believe it's better to drive OpenGL rather than let it drive you.

```
enum EMode { ...etc };

EMode menu();
void single();
void multi();

int main()
  {
    init(...);
    bool loop = true;
    while(loop)
      {
        switch(menu())
          {
            case EMode.single:
              game_loop(1);
              break;
            case EMode.multi:
              game_loop(2);
              break;
            case quit:
              loop = false;
            ...etc
          }
      }
    finish(...);
    return 0;
  }
```

Simple menu loop. (Forgive my code style it's different than usual).
It's not a great layout, but it would work for a simple game.

- `init()` initializes openGL.
- `menu()`, `single()` and `multi()` each have their own loops, which render and swap the buffers manually.
- `menu()` returns a value specifying which menu item was chosen.

Game loop that runs at constant speed and doesn't waste CPU.

```
void game_loop(int players)
  {
    CGame game = new Game(players);
    bool loop = true;
    time_type next_frame = get_time() - 1;
    while(loop)
      {
        time_type time = get_time();
        if(time > next_frame)
          {
            do_input(game);
            while(time > next_frame)
              {
                game.tick();
                next_frame += frame_period;
              }
            do_render(game); // draw stuff here, and swap buffers.
          }
        else
          {
            // Don't waste CPU (optional).
            wait_till(next_frame);
          }
      }
  }
```

Again, not wonderful, but function enough. (I use something like this).

- CGame is the game class (if you want to be OO).
- get_time(), wait_till(), time_type etc are all made up. Use whatever function/type suits.

Quick and off the top of my head - probably even has some bugs - but it could give you an idea.